# How do I know which properties are under spring.jpa.properties

Tags: spring-data-jpa

When configuring springboot's application.properties, how do I know which properties can be configured under spring.jpa.properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring's [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html) is a great place to start.

You'll be interested in the **DATA** section

If you'd like to know what a specific JPA provider offers, take a look at the concrete provider's documentation, [hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) for example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

but what i want to know is
such as:
spring.jpa.properties.*  --> Additional native properties to set on the JPA provider.

where i can find these [native properties].

Comment: For that, you'll have to check your specific jpa provider documentation, for example if you are interested in hibernate, check it [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-hibernatejdbc) and just combine what's in the table with the prefix of spring.jpa.proprerties.* - you'll end up with something like that:
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect